# Content nowrap and position fixed footer

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page which has a fixed footer div. It should be horizontally centered and at the bottom of the page. My code works fine if there is no much text on the page. If there is more text and the fixed footer div gets out of the screen, it disappears. I do not know why is that happening.

So, this works fine:

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid blue; white-space: nowrap;">
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
</div>
<div style="width: 1050px; border: 1px solid red; left: 50%; margin-left: -525px; position: fixed; text-align: center;">
  This is the footer
</div>
```

But when there is more text and the footer gets out of the screen, it disappears. How could I fix this? Please note that the text on my content div should not be wrapped.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid blue; white-space: nowrap;">
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
  <p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
</div>
<div style="width: 1050px; border: 1px solid red; left: 50%; margin-left: -525px; position: fixed; text-align: center;">
  This is the footer
</div>
```

Comment: you need to fix the `left`, `position` and  `margin-left` properties appropriately. removing three of them makes the footer appear

Comment: How should I do it?

Comment: Just put `bottom: 0;` on the footer style to make it appear and remove the `white-space: nowrap;`

But got to tell you that this doesn't look like good code to me.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, the text should not be wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
<p>The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here. The content goes here. Whatever I want to display on the page itself gets put here.</p>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; text-align: center;">
This is the footer
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Almost OK, but the text should not be wrapped.